# Easily compare recent changes after format changed

Tags: eclipse

Before comiting I want to check my recent changes... the problem is that the format has changed automtically and I want to see the real changes made in the code and not the format changes... is there any way to just see the code changes and not all changes in eclipse ? I also don't want to revert to latest revision and then change the format to the old one and add then add the code ....

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about whitespace, the option to ignore it is in: 
Window > Preferences > General > Compare/Patch > Ignore white space

Comment: no... I meant if for instance the line format has been changed from 120 to 80 signs, which means there are a lot of line breaks now, thus for eclipse everything in the code has changed... but I just want to see the real code changes ...

Comment: Wow, that's certainly not ideal. I know ignoring line breaks is a feature that's being worked on for a future version of Beyond Compare,  but it's not even currently in the BC4 beta.